# How to convert System.currentMillisSeconds to a TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, milliseconds, temporal

I need to convert a standard long System.currentmillis to a temporal accessor and have no clue how to even begin.

Comment: The place to start is the javadoc ... for `TemporalAccessor` and the classes that implement it.

Comment: A very funny requirement. Does it stand alone? A trait of a `TemporalAccessor` is that it supports one or more `TemporalField`s, so I wonder if there’s any requirement about which field(s) it should support? (`Instant` mentioned in the answer supports `NANO_OF_SECOND`, `MICRO_OF_SECOND`, `MILLI_OF_SECOND` and `INSTANT_SECONDS`, which is a reasonable set coming from milliseconds since the epoch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a `TemporalAccessor`, so you can create an `Instant` from a number of milliseconds since the epoch:

```
TemporalAccessor ta = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Note that the docs for [`System.currentTimeMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) says that the granularity of the value depends on the OS, so it might not be the exact time in milliseconds.

> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of
>   time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the
>   value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger.
>   For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of
>   milliseconds.